# Does Dark Souls 2 have a level cap?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am still in my first run through the game, currently in the Lost Bastille and my char is on Level 76.  Since many games have a cap at around 100 (or even earlier) I am wondering how far I can go here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no strict upper limit on your level in the Souls series, including Dark Souls 2. Instead each of your individual stats has an upper limit of 99. Once you've maxed out all your stats you won't be able to level up any further. Additionally, since every class starts at a different level and with different stats there's no universal level cap, although each individual class does have a maximum level they can reach.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! So for a normal playthrough I most probably won't have any limitation.

Comment: Level cap is not really the problem. Even though in this one you can respec, you have to be careful that you don't spread your stats too thin because you will have trouble leveling up any stats you may need later.

Answer (score 12):

According to this [Dark Souls 2](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Stats#Stats-Level) wiki article:

- The highest possible level attainable is 838.
- With all stats leveled to 99, the maximum Health is 2505.

Answer (score 5):

I am currently level 243 with a relatively symmetrical stat build. The only stats above 40 are vitality and endurance (this method appeases my ocd.) I can say that being on my third playthrough with a few bonfires raised with an ascetic to five that it's not nearly as bad getting 250k souls to level as it is in DS1 and demons souls. There are strategies in place to aid the power leveler, and given that vigor was added as the health stat to separate endurance and vitality into two categories of stamina and equip load and adaptability was introduced I would say the highest level would be universally higher than 712.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently level 370, but I have completed ng+7 completely, only left is PvP and farming levels, but that seems to be an useless idea. So you don't have to worry about the level cap since you don't reach it unless you want to.

E: And just to let you know, leveling up costs 400k souls for me now